# mat-input still remains invalid after successful validation - Angular 12

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, mat-input, mat-error

**Component code-**

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
          currentPassword: ['', [Validators.required], [this.matchCurrentPassword]],
          newPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(12)]],
          confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required]]
        }
          , { validator: this.ConfirmedValidator('newPassword', 'confirmPassword') }
        )
      }
    matchCurrentPassword = (
        control: AbstractControl
      ): Observable<ValidationErrors | ValidationErrors> => {
        return this.userService.matchCurrentPassword(localStorage.getItem("userId"), control.value)
          .pipe
          (tap(x => { console.log("response:", x) }),
            (map((x: any) => { return x.isExecute ? { matches: true } : { matches: false }; }))
          )
      }
ConfirmedValidator(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
      const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
      const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];
      if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors.confirmedValidator) {
        return;
      }
      if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
        matchingControl.setErrors({ confirmedValidator: true });
      } else {
        matchingControl.setErrors(null);
      }
    }
  }
```

**Html code-**

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="1 1 calc(100% - 10px)"fxFlex.lt-md="1 1 calc(100% - 10px)" fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%" class="from-color">
    <mat-label class="label-padding">Enter Current Password</mat-label>
     <input type="password" class="label-padding" type="text" style="-webkit-text-security: disc;"matInput placeholder="Current Password" formControlName="currentPassword" />
   <mat-error *ngIf="currentPassword.errors?.required && currentPassword.touched">Enter current password</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="currentPassword.errors?.matches==false">Doesn't match</mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>
```

The validation for **matching current password** works perfectly & shows error message according to the condition. But its input field **remains invalid** after that.

I've also tried validating rest of the input fields. But the **currentPassword** remains invalid &  that causes the **entire form** remaining **invalid**.

Why is this happening & how to solve this? Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please show your `ConfirmedValidator` function.

Comment: @JsNgian I've edited the question. But, let me inform you, the **ConfirmedValidator** is **working fine & doesn't have any issue** of remaining invalid even after validation.

Comment: What dose `matchCurrentPassword` do here. what are you matching your password against (`{ return x.isExecute ? { matches: true } : { matches: false }; }`) ?

Comment: @JsNgian The scenario is, if any user wants to **change** his password, he must enter his current password which I'm **passing to the backend** & **matching with the existing(current) password** of that user. If passwords don't match it will show error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Defining custom validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators),

> That function takes an Angular control object and returns either null if the control value is valid or a validation error object.

You need to **return `null` for `matchCurrentPassword` function if the validation is valid**.

---

### Solution

And return `{ matches: true }` in `matchCurrentPassword` function when the validation is failed.

> .component.ts

```js
matchCurrentPassword = (
  control: AbstractControl
): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
  let userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
  return this.userService.matchCurrentPassword(userId, control.value).pipe(
    tap(x => {
      console.log('response:', x);
    }),
    map((x: any) => {
      return x.isExecute ? null : { matches: true };
    })
  );
};
```

> .component.html

```
<mat-error *ngIf="currentPassword.errors?.matches">Doesn't match</mat-error>
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9qnbuu)

Comment: Thanks. I've few questions here

{ return x.isExecute ? null :  { matches: false } } here, does the **sequence of returning** null & the { matches: false } matter? Also, Observable<ValidationErrors | null> here should I match the **return sequence** with the **structure sequence**? Lastly, why does **Observable<ValidationErrors | null>** & **Observable<ValidationErrors | ValidationErrors> both work**?

Comment: 1. It depends on your logic, ensure that return `null` for validation success case. 2. This is more like the developer's opinion. In my opinion, as long the return value match with the function's return type that would be fine. 3. I corrected my answer, it should be `Observable<ValidationErrors | null>`.